# generate select option (html) from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this two array
i want get ('**mohsen**' / '**hosein**') as array1 and get ('**ali**' , '**hasan**') as array2

i have a foreach loop, i want generate this output :

Select 1 (array 1):

```
<select>
<option>mohsen</option>
<option>hosein</option>
</select>
```

Select 2 (array 2):

```
<select>
<option>ali</option>
<option>hasan</option>
</select>
```

array 1 :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_item"]=>
    string(6) "mohsen"
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_true"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_item"]=>
    string(6) "hosein"
  }
}
```

array 2 :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_item"]=>
    string(3) "ali"
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_true"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["answer_key_val_select_front_of_question_item"]=>
    string(5) "hasan"
  }
}
```

Comment: What have tried so far? We do not write the code for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i generate this both array with foreach loop code , i want print this :

mohsen - hosein
ali - hasan

i have duplicate index in both array (0,1 - 0,1) , for this reason i dont do print this :

mohsen - hosein
ali - hasan